# How do I reset a form after submission?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

Please see the code below, this all works as expected with two exceptions

1. The form holds the data after submission.  I have tried using the reset() method but this did not work.
2. The dropdowns need a selection, I attempted to put a default case in my switch statement that provided an alert window but this didn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    /* Base Styles -------------------- */

      h2 {
        padding-top: 20px;
      }
      textarea {
        outline: none;
        resize: none;
      }

      /* Main Styles --------------------- */

      .main-header {
        margin: 10px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .inputField {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="primary-content container">
        <header class="main-header text-center">
          <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18nwgWOUu2V5NVV4hbR8a2uOesL5JF1OL" alt="AUE">
          <p class="lead">Helping people.</p>
        </header>
        <div id="container" class="primary-content form-group">
          <h2>Contact us</h2><br>
          <form id="responderForm">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" class="input-field form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name:" required><br>
              </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" name="lastName" class="input-field form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name:" required><br>
               </div>
            </div>
              <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field form-control" placeholder="Email:" required><br>
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <label class="input-group-text" for="service">Enquiry options</label>
              </div>
                <select class="custom-select" id="service" required>
                  <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="My enquiry is about:">
                    <option value="Choose" name="service" disabled selected>Please choose from the list below:</option>
                    <option value="Home Help" name="service">Home Help</option>
                    <option value="Befriending" name="service">Befriending</option>
                    <option value="Information & Advice" name="service">Information &amp; Advice</option>
                    <option value="Volunteering" name="service">Volunteering</option>
                    <option value="Donations" name="service">Making a donation</option>
                    <option value="Fundraising" name="service">Fundraising</option>
                    <option value="Media" name="service">Media requests</option>
                    <option value="Invoice Query" name="service">Making a payment</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="Your feedback:">
                    <option value="compliment" name="feedback">Let us know how we are doing</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="Change how we contact you">
                    <option value="Consent" name="gdprRights">Update your staying connected options</option>
                  </optgroup>
                  <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="None of the above:">
                    <option value="other" name="feedback">For any enquiries not listed above please specify below.</option>
                  </optgroup><br>
             </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label class="input-group-text" for="message">Message options</label>
          </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="message" required>
              <option value="Choose" name="message" disabled selected>Please select type of message below:</option>
              <option value=" General enquiry" name="message">General Enquiry</option>
              <option value="Request for information" name="message">Request for information</option>
              <option value="Donation enquiry" name="message">Donation Enquiry</option>
              <option value="Invoice/Payments enquiry" name="message">Invoice/Payment Enquiry</option>
              <option value="Feedback" name="message">Feedback</option>
              <option value="Something else" name="message">Something else</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <textarea id="enquiry_form" class="text-input form-control" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea><br><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="event input-field btn btn-outline btn-primary"><br><br>
        </form>
      </div>
      <p class="lead">If you are interested in working for us, please click <a href="https://www.ageuk.org.uk/essex/about-us/work-for-us/" target="_blank">HERE:</a></p>
      <footer class="main-footer text-center lead">
        <address >
          <p>AUE</p>
          <telephone>Telephone:</telephone>
          <p>&copy; </p>
        </address>
      </footer>
      <script>
        const myForm = document.querySelector('#responderForm');
        console.log(myForm);
        myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let myData = {
        'first' : this.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]').value,
        'last' : this.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]').value,
        'email' : this.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
        'service' : this.querySelector('select[id="service"]').value,
        'enquiryType' : this.querySelector('select[id="message"]').value,
        'enquiry': this.querySelector('textarea[id="enquiry_form"]').value
        }

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).addData(myData);
        console.dir(myData);
        })

        function onSuccess(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
     </script>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e){
  try {
    var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    var html = output.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    return html;
  }
  catch(e){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'error' : e
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function getRandom(){
   return (new Date().getTime()).toString(36); 
}

function addData(data){
  console.log(data);
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EcjX0SjZpX7qRyDuNOKdiXovgrV3au');
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Response');
   var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var createdDate = Date();
   var newId = getRandom();
   var holder = [data.first,data.last,data.email, createdDate, newId, data.service, data.enquiry, user, data.enquiryType];
   sheet.appendRow(holder);
   var services = [data.first, data.last,data.service, createdDate, newId, data.enquiry, user, data.enquiryType];
   sendAnEmail(holder, services);
  switch(data.service){
    case 'Volunteering':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Home Help':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Befriending':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Information & Advice':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Donations':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Fundraising':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      case 'Media':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Invoice Query':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Compliment':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Consent':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'other':
      var mailAddress = 'aps@testemail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
  }
   return {
    'trackingid':newId,
    'status':true,
    'added': holder
  }

  function sendAnEmail(holder, services){
     var emailAddress = holder[2] || Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
     var message = '<h1>Thank you for your enquiry, '+holder[0]+'</h1><br><h4>Your message has been received successfully.</h4> <p> Your enquiry has been passed to the relevant team and we endeavour to respond to all enquiries within 24 hours Mon - Friday.</p> ';
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, ""+holder[0]+" your Query ID: "+holder[4]+" has been received.", '',{
      htmlBody:message,
      name:'AUE',
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: You can redirect on success to a "thank you" page / a refreshed version of the WebApp.

Comment: @ziganotschka I added a reset function which clears the data from the form as expected.  I like the idea of redirecting though as currently it just clears which isn't particularly user friendly.  How would I redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just clear all of the elements that contain data here:

```
function onSuccess({//Reset data in here;})
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thank you I tried this and it hasn't worked :(

function onSuccess(data){
  console.log(data);
  reset(data);
}

Comment: Is reset(data) a function you wrote?  It's not in your question.

Comment: No, it’s a JavaScript method that I assumed (wrongly it seems) I’d need to use?

Comment: I was thinking you do something like this: `this.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]').value=''`

Comment: There is a method `HTMLFormElement.reset()` found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

Answer (score 0):

### How to redirect on form submit

On FormSubmit you can either

- redirect to the empty, refreshed version of your current page
- redirect to a new page, e.g. a "Thank You" page

What you need to do is to add an [onclick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) to your `submit` button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.top.location.href='XXX'"; name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="event input-field btn btn-outline btn-primary">
```

- Hereby `XXX` can be replaced either through the URL of your WebApp or any other URL you desire
- If you want to create a "Thank You" page with Apps Script, the easiest way would be to create a new WebApp with the content:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Thank you for submitting this form!");
}
```

- Deploy the script with this content as a WebApp, note its URL and use this URL to replace the `XXX`